# How do I allow an item in a collection inform its parent(s) of state changes

Tags: c#, oop

I'm currently having an issue in working out how a child in a collection can communicate "up the chain" without passing a reference of the parent to it.

When I started the project I wanted to keep children independent from their parents (Read it somewhere). But now I've hit a bit of wall of when I want to log event's

I've prepared a basic example how the structure of what I'm working with below.

```
class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    /**
     * Note: in the application this List is actaually a seperate class 
     * for loading / saving of attributes.
     **/
    public List<AttributeA> AttributeACollection = new List<AttributeA>();

    public void LoadById(int productId)
    {
        /** 
         * Load all product data including filling AttributeACollection
         **/
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        /**
         * Goes through AtrributeACollection 
         * checks for new / edited / deleted AttributeA's
         * Saves to database 
         **/
    }

    public static string GetProductCodeById(int productId) 
    { 
        /**
         * Return product name by searching the product table using product ID.
         **/
    }

}

class AttributeA
{

    /** 
     * The database id of the product
     * this attribute is attached to 
     **/
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    /**
     * The id of the of AttributesA variation 
     * (e.g. if the attribute was size the variation 
     * id might point to "Large" 
     **/
    public int AttribiteId { get; set; }

    /**
     * The name of the selected variation for this attribute 
     **/
    public string AttributeName {get;set;}

    /**
     * The database id of the relation 
     * between product Id and Attribute id
     **/
    public int VariationId { get; set; }

    public void LoadById(int variationId) { }

    public void LoadByProductIdAndAttributeId(int productId, int attributeId) { }

    public void Save() 
    {
        /**
         * If I want to log a change here I have to call
         * the static Product.GetProductCodeById to log with the
         * product code. 
         **/
    }

    public void Delete() {}

}
```

Although in the example above it would be easy to pass a reference of the parent, in the actual application attributes have lists of attributes and I don't feel having a never ending list of "parent" is the right way.

I've looked into 3 different ways

1. A logging class that gets passed down the chain (feels like a
   bandage, as other issues apart from logging will come out of not
   having access to the parent)
2. Just pass the parent to the child
3. Events.. Events seem like the way to go, but I have little
   experience with their implementation so would need to make sure they
   are the right way before I dive in!

The reason I would want to communicate "up the chain" is currently for logging purposes. If I wanted to log say "ProductCodeXYX => Removed Large From AttributeA" I would have to get the name of the product from inside the AttributeA class (Which I currently do with a static class, which is double loading the data).

Comment: Why do you want to do this. It seems like a bad design. Why should the child know or care if it's in one or more containers?

Comment: I've made an edit to hopefully explain "why" at the bottom.

Comment: what about many parents ?

Comment: Logging should never cause you to change the basic design of your objects. This is a very bad idea.

Comment: It's not just for logging purposes, that was just an example. Another example may be updating the UI when a attribute was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about events? The child can raise an event when it's attribute is modified and the parent can handle it. In this way the child need not have a reference of it's parent.

Comment: This is what I have been leaning towards the most (See my 3 points). But seeing as I have coded myself into a corner I want to make sure I solve this correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP - the object at runtime will have a reference to the parent through the event, but it doesnt need a reference at design time.

Comment: sorry @james.. missed the event part in your question. Anyway, I would prefer events in this case.

Comment: No problem @Baga, thank you for your input. I've been trying to get my head around events struggling to see how to implement them.

Comment: @PhillipH, thanks for the clarification. Would that make it a "bad design"?

Comment: No - its how all change notification happens in WPF (look up the INotifyPropertyChange interface to see that Controls can notify their Parents when they've changed). You just need to be sure to de-allocate the Event Handler (i.e. myThing.OnChange -= myEventHandler) when the parent no longer owns it (typically on collection.Remove).